# How to make onload run in customize_controls_enqueue_scripts context WordPress Theme Customizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress, and trying to make a child theme with customizer options.

For part of this, I have code that can only run only once an image has loaded, and I want to use information from the image to update other customize settings. I have both of these things working seperately.

When I enqueue the javascript in `customize_preview_init`, the image loads fine and I am able to do operations on it, but I cannot update other customizer settings. When I enqueue the javascript in `customize_controls_enqueue_script`s, `onload` no longer works, but I can set the other setting to things (outside of onload)

How do I have onload run in a script enqueued in `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`, or is there a better way to accomplish this? Thank you!!

**In my customizer class constructer:**

`add_action(`  `'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'` or `'customize_preview_init'` `, array( $this, 'my_link_js') );`

**In link_test.js:**

```
( function( $ ) {
    wp.customize( 'logo1', 'setting1', function( value, setting1) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) { //on logo upload?
            var image_in = new Image;            
            image_in.onload = function(){ 
                console.log("here?"); //this never happens
                //[Image processing things happen, a settingFromImage variable is created] 
                setting1.set(settingFromImage);                
            }
            image_in.src = newval;
            setting1.set(arbitraryValue); //works if tried here 
        } );
        
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```